# Don't understand Guava PrimitiveSink

Tags: java, hash, guava

I thought about learning some new things and started to use Google Guava in a new small project.

One of the first things I have to do, was to implement a simple key exchange based authentication.

The plan was, to combine some values, and generate a SHA256 hash.

In pure Java it's

```
    final String toHash = id + ts + secret;
    final MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
    final byte[] hash = digest.digest(toHash.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    final String result = getHexFormated(hash)
```

In Guava I tried

```
    final Hasher hasher = Hashing.sha256().newHasher().putString(id, Charsets.UTF_8)
        .putLong(ts).putString(secret, Charsets.UTF_8);
    final HashCode hashcode = hasher.hash();
```

If I compare the first result with hashcode.toString() it's completely different.
If I compare the byte[] itself, to take care, that not getHexFormated is wrong, also the byte arrays are absolutely different.

So what is the problem here? What does a PrimitiveSink instead of simple combining the given values?

Comment: In your first code snippet, you convert your `long` to a `String`; in the second, you put the `long` value directly! Try and put `String.valueOf(ts)` instead of `ts`.

Comment: You are right, that's it. Can you post it as the answer, so I can vote it. So what is the PrimitiveSink doing here? It doesn't simply combine the parts right?

Comment: Well, in effect, a `PrimitiveSink` does nothing, it is just an interface which is supposed to swallow everything you throw at it; a `Hasher` simply implements that interface (and turns everything into `byte`s, as it turns out).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your first snippet you do:

```
final String toHash = id + ts + secret;
```

where `ts` is a `long`; however, in the above statement, it will be appended as a string.

In your second snippet, you do:

```
.putLong(ts)
```

As such, your output will differ... You should

```
.putString(String.valueOf(ts))
```

instead.